# Export received dataset to array

Tags: java, dataset, export, firebase

I need to export the data from my firebase dataset to an array. Here is my code:

```
Firebase fb = new Firebase("https://----.firebaseio.com/");
Query q = fb.orderByKey();

q.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        iterator = snapshot.getChildren().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            // The code I need goes here
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```

This code is inside a method that is supposed to return an array of data, however exporting this to a local variable in the enclosing method doesn't do the job. Does anyone have a better way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you expect the `addValueEventListener` invocation to block the execution of your method, which this code is inside, until the `onDataChange` callback has been invoked?

Comment: @cyon All I need is for that data to be exported to a variable that I can use in that method. So yes, the invocation should block the execution until the data has been retrieved.

Comment: And what should happen the next time the data changes?

Comment: @cyon The data will be reloaded into the array whenever the method is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback will be invoked asynchronously, which means that it may not have happened before your method finishes.

It sounds like you want to have a method that when invoked will query the latest state of the data. What you can do is create the firebase connection and attach the listener outside of your method (maybe inside your `main` method) and have your method query the listener for the latest data.

```
class CustomValueListener implements ValueEventListener {    
    private volatile DataSnapshop data; //accessed from multiple threads
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        data = snapshot;
    }    
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}
    public DataSnapshot getLatestData() {
        return data;
    }
}
private CustomValueListener listener = new CustomValueListener();

public static void main(String...args) {
     ...     
     Firebase fb = new Firebase("https://----.firebaseio.com/");
     Query q = fb.orderByKey();    
     q.addValueEventListener(listener);
     ...
}
String[] yourMethod() {
     ...
     Sring[] result = ...
     DataSnapshot snapshot = listener.getLatestData();
     if (snapshot != null) {
        iterator = snapshot.getChildren().iterator();
         while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            //now you can copy the data into the array 
         }
     }
     return result;
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, and I get a NullPointerException on the snapshot variable in yourMethod(). BTW, I put the code in your `main` into the constructor of my class.

Comment: @SalmonKiller Try putting some logging in the `onDataChange` and `onCancelled` methods or try putting breakpoints there while debugging. It could be that you are having trouble connecting to firebase.

Comment: The problem was that the request was asynchrounous. I added a semaphore and it started working. Thanks for all the help.